# why would this happen? - strange keyup keydown events on my machine

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, keyboard-events

Here's some javascript:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
        console.log("keydown: " + event.keyCode);
    });
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
        console.log("keyup: " + event.keyCode);
    });
```

Here's the result of me pressing and releasing a key just once:

```
keyup: 17
keydown: 68
keyup: 17
keyup: 68
```

This is specific to my machine. Why would this be happening?

Note: I discovered this weirdness in flash, where the KeyboardEvents were being fired off in the same way.

Comment: It may be because that is `ctrl`+`d` which in Chrome is the shortcut to bookmark the page, so the page looses focus one the bookmark alert shows up

Comment: So your control key is stuck? :)

Comment: Browsers behavior varies when dealing with CTRL key combination events. And your CTRL key is stuck :)

I have to say, for a first question on the site that's a well-written question. Welcome to SO!

Comment: `CTRL` + `d` is the shortcut to bookmark a page in all ( at least standard ) browsers ( ie, firefox, chrome, opera, safari, ... ) I tested the code in 6 of them in my windows 7 and never got an abnormal result ! For flash, are you speaking about flash player standalone, in the browser or just when testing your swf in flash ide ?

Comment: Theses results are from pressing and releasing the D key only.  The Ctrl key is never actually touched.  If I press and release the Ctrl key, the results would show that I pressed Ctrl twice, then released Ctrl twice.

Comment: As a side note, I did check if sticky keys were the issue but that wasn't it.

Comment: Have you tried running the code in a different computer and/or connecting a different keyboard, just to rule out the possibility of a problem with the keyboard? Does the D key work correctly as expected in other applications (such as  a text editor, for example) using the same keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

according to: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

- keycode 17 = ctrl
- keycode 68 = d

Your code is detecting that the CTRL key is being released when you press the d key. This is not specific to your machine, this is specific to your peripheral devices or malicious software running on your machine or excessive code being executed.

---

About the event handler:

The addEventHandler method has has a third parameter known as the useCapture which handles the order of execution during the capturing or bubbling phase.
The capturing phase is fired as soon as the event is triggered.
The bubbling phase is triggered on exit of the triggered event.